# Проблемы с модулем Selenium (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Я попробовал попарсить и у меня это получалось но не все. Модуль requests работал отлично но не загружал весь документ html, я нашел чудесный модуль Selenium, но когда я пытаюсь подключиться или что я там делаю выводиться ошибка: `raise WebDriverException( selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see  https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home`, честно решаю эту задачку уже второй день и все не могу найти понятный ответ вот очень простой код который где я пытаюсь получить полный html документ:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
print(driver.get('https://google.com/'))
```

Comment: Ну а по указанной ссылке вы перешли и сам chromedriver скачали?

Comment: А как его устанавливать? Об этом я слышал и пытался как то этот драйвер подключить но не получалось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы Selenium нужен chromedriver той же версии, что и ваш браузер на компьютере. И программа на питоне должна знать где находится исполняемые файл chromedriver. Для этого можно добавит путь до папки с ним в переменную окружения PATH или разместить chromedriver в директории с проектом на питоне.

Comment: Спасибо заработало!

Comment: @Salatosik Пожалуйста. Отметьте тогда ответ галочкой :)

Comment: Я новичок на этом сайте, не знал)